# Differentiate $\frac{3x-6}{x}$

Tags: derivatives

This should be fairly simple but I'm missing something. The way that I derived this equation was 
$$f(x)=\frac{3x-6}{x}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{3(1x^0)-0}{1x^0}=\frac{3}{1}=3$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: $$f(x) = x$$ is a function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quotient rule

$$f’(x)=\frac{3x-(3x-6)}{x^2}=\frac 6{x^2}$$

as an alternative

$$f(x)=\frac{3x-6}{x}=3-\frac 6 x\implies f’(x)=\frac 6{x^2}$$

Comment: in the alternate process you use, how o you go from the first step to the second step? and not only that, but why is it that you do that step? to simplify?

Comment: We simply have $$\frac{3x-6}{x}=\frac{3x}{x}-\frac{6}{x}=3-\frac{6}{x}$$ It simplify because we can use that the derivative of a constant is zero and that $(1/x)’=-1/x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot differentiate numerator and denominator separately.

- While you could use the *quotient rule* $(*)$, I usually try to avoid it when that's easily done:
  $$\left(\frac{3x-6}{x}\right)'=\left(3-\frac{6}{x}\right)'=\left(3-6x^{-1}\right)'=6x^{-2}=\frac{6}{x^2}$$
- With the *quotient rule* $(*)$:
  $$\left(\frac{3x-6}{x}\right)'=\frac{(3x-6)'x-(3x-6)x'}{x^2}=\frac{3x-(3x-6)}{x^2}=\frac{6}{x^2}$$

---

$(*)$ the **quotient rule** tells you how to differentiate fractions:
$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$$
Note how this is (very) different from $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$...!

Answer (score 1):

If one has to go by definition, then
$$f'(a) = \lim _{x\to a}  \left (\frac{3x-6}{x} -\frac{3a-6}{a}\right ) \cdot \frac{1}{x-a} = \lim _{x\to a} \frac{6x-6a}{ax(x-a)} = \frac{6}{a^2}  $$